# Invisible component in SSIS Dataflow package

Tags: ssis

Everytime I run my data flow component, it gives me a validation error on a component whose name I cannot find in the editor! I think it happpened when I did ctrl-c on an existing component, and did ctrl-v. and it was successfully pasted, but somehow I can't see it, and therefore can't remove it!. My package is damaged as a result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see it in the XML when you select View..Code in Visual Studio?  Or can you select it from the object drop down list in the Properties window?